# How do you dynamically assign a list of buttons the same function but different arguments?

Tags: python, button, tkinter, dynamic, command

I have a python program using Tkinter that dynamically creates buttons that are identical except for their position/index. The buttons are created through a loop and are stored in a list. Therefore the buttons are only identifiable via their index in the list.

I am trying to loop through this list later and assign the buttons a function who's only argument is that button's indexed position in the list. For example:

```
for i in range(len(button_list)):
button_list[i].config(command=lambda: start_time(button_list[i]))
```

Because the argument is assigned when the button is clicked rather than when the function is assigned to the button, clicking any button always activates what should be the final button's function instead of its own function.

Is there a way to assign an argument to the function when the function is assigned to the button?

Here is the window with the buttons:
[Window with Buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D2lPo.png)

Here is a hard-coded example of what I'm trying to do:

```
button_list[0].config(command=lambda: start_time(0))
button_list[1].config(command=lambda: start_time(1))
button_list[2].config(command=lambda: start_time(2))
```

I've also tried this:

```
index_list = list(range(len(button_list)))
for x in index_list:
    onclick = lambda index=x: start_time(x)
    button_list[x].config(command=onclick)
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

EDIT: Here is some more of my code to give more context for the sake of clarity:

```
def start_time(index):
now_local = datetime.now()
hour = now_local.strftime("%H")
minute = now_local.strftime("%M")
second = now_local.strftime("%S")

global time_start
time_start = [hour, minute, second]

global button_list
button_list[index].config(text="Stop", command=lambda: end_time(index))

    for i in range(len(button_list)):
    if i == index:
        continue
    else:
        button_list[i].config(state=DISABLED)
```

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but why make that range into a list?

Comment: No reason related to this particular code. Its a left over from me trying other things to find a workable solution. Sorry for the added confusion

Comment: No worries! I just realized you could simplify things further by using `enumerate()`, it’s perfect for this.

Comment: As you were posting I was writing the same thing...and forgetting the enumerate part and the parentheses..

Comment: As for your question, I think we might need a bit more detail to find the ideal solution.

Comment: `for i,btn in enumerate(button_list): btn.config(command=lambda i=i: start_time(i))`.

Comment: Is it possible for a button to call itself? Or in some way identify itself upon being clicked?

Comment: `btn.config(command=lambda b=btn: start_time(b))`.  Is this what you want?

Comment: awc1668, your first response worked. I'm trying to turn your response into an answer to give credit where its due. New to posting on this site

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure what you are asking, but if I understand you right you want to assign the index of the button list to the `start(time)` within the config file for that indexed button.

If I am understanding right you can use `enumerate()` to solve the problem:

```
for ind, button in enumerate(button_list):
    button_list[ind].config(command= lambda: start_time(ind)
```

Comment: Thanks, but this results in the same issue. At the time of pressing the button, Python passes the final value of "ind" at the end of this for loop to start_time(), therefore when you press the top button (or any button for that matter) it actives what the final button is supposed to activate.

Comment: I think I misunderstood what you were asking for...if you are hoping to assessing the values in the loop at the time of clicking, you will ALWAYS end up with the last index in the iterator. I though you were using this to set a .config permanently so that when a button was selected it would align. Your added code is helpful!